# Re-host a website in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, html, sockets, web

### **This is a unusual question (keep that in mind)**

### **1. The idea.**

There is a computer that has a website hosted on the web browser via JavaScript and other computers can connect to that website and access it, once that computer has loaded the website on it's browser then other computers can access it from that computer, so as long as there is a active user on the website at the moment running the JavaScript that is hosting it then the website is online. Once there is no one on it it goes offline can can't get online again.

### **2. The purpose**

The purpose of a non server based website is that it would, well not have a server which can therefore cannot be taken down no matter what as long as the users use it, it cannot be traced too since you connect to it via different public IP addresses. How do you know what address you should connect to? I don't know yet, maybe logging the computers that have accessed it on the website source code and then pining those to see if they are online, not sure myself. All this allows for complete anonymity and no trace ability, but finding a way to refresh all the sites without immense computational power to dispose is also still a mystery for me.

### **3. The question**

How do i host a website on the JavaScript that is available to execute on web browser or is it even possible. If it is not then is there a possibility to create a library for the JavaScript and embed it in the source code of the site? If that does not work, what way is there to make a P2P based website that can refresh at a modest speed?

### **3.1 The question (Re-clarified because some ZGljaw0K thought so)**

How do i host a website on the JavaScript that is run on a web browser?

Comment: a website hosted on the web browser via Javascript? to host a web site via Javascript you use node.js

Comment: it sounds like you're talking about screen sharing. You load the website on the computer, then you allow other computers to take over the console, using RDP or VNC.

Comment: No i'm not talking about screen sharing, i want to host a website on a websites JavaScript.

Comment: If it's a website allowing other computers to connect to it, that's the definition of a server.

Comment: If you host it on a laptop, then that laptop becomes a server. That can be taken down even easier that a server server

Comment: Yes but not in the sense of a Server that can always serve but it's dynamic.

Comment: So you want to write a web server in JavaScript that runs in the browser?  I doubt the browser *itself* is going to allow this.  At least not without some custom plugins of some kind.  Web browsers generally run JavaScript in a sandbox, and generally don't listen on ports for external connections.  I guess the real question is... What are you actually trying to accomplish by doing this and why?  It seems like you're taking the wrong approach.

Comment: Either you are not describing what you are thinking about very well, or you are talking ovoids

Comment: There's nothing wrong with this question.  Those of you knocking it aren't very open minded and should probably just move along.

Comment: Yeah exactly, that is what i want to do. Well can't you set JavaScript to listen to external connections that want to be made?

Comment: This is very intriguing but consider this: does each visitor need to download **ALL** of your web pages before they are granted access to their requested page? How quickly would this get out of sync? How do you know that your current peer has the latest version of the web page? If I visit your page once and never visit your site again then my computer would always have an old version of the site? If you were to implement a crawling mechanism to get the latest version then how does the browser know which peer has the latest version?

Comment: If your P2P site is heavy on the images then it would be daunting to start acting as a seed for other visitors.

Comment: Yeah i know that is a large problem, but it can probably be solved with modest resources spent.

Comment: So you essentially want to create a P2P hosting solution, or you want users to download the entire site before accessing it?

Comment: Yeah, as the question states, P2P hosting and the entire site is loaded at once from one client. How is this to broad, it makes no sense to flag it as that.

Comment: This question is not too broad.  It's fine as-is.  A bunch of people don't know what they're talking about, and are making assumptions about what you're trying to do.  This is a common problem when you ask anything that is a bit strange on Stack Overflow, but it's definitely not your fault @Full_Nitrous.

Comment: @Brad, Well in then i understand why my question got put on hold but, how do i remove it from being on hold since it is a valid question that others may gain knowledge from or get their question answered from?

Comment: Unfortunately you can't, unless a decent amount of people vote to re-open it.  I voted to do that... 2 other people have to come buy and vote to do the same within the next week or so.  It probably won't happen.

Answer (score 2):

This is not only possible, [it's commonly done](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peer-to-peer_web_hosting)!

There are some caveats though.  First, to make peer-to-peer (P2P) connections in-browser, you need to use WebRTC.  To make a WebRTC connection, the browsers first have to communicate over a signalling channel to negotiate protocol version, any media channels (if used), and what addresses to connect with.  That signalling channel generally requires a server.  (There are some neat WebRTC signalling methods that use QR Codes to send data visually... but those only work if the devices' cameras can see the other screen, such as in the same room.)

Because of this requirement, and the extra overhead of distribution, P2P web serving is usually reserved for bandwidth intensive requests, such as HD video segments.  There are commercial products for this:  https://www.peer5.com/

Also, check out WebTorrent.  https://webtorrent.io/  There are many projects built off of it around what you are asking.